# nestjs route exclude file extensions

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, nestjs

Hi for a couple of days I have this challenge

I'm building with NestJS (https://nestjs.com/)

I want to have a route that only listens when it doesn't have a file extension.

So for example

```
localhost:3000 -> good
localhost:3000/ -> good
localhost:3000/test -> good
localhost:3000/test.txt -> ignore
localhost:3000/css/mycss.css -> ignore
```

Also, when the route is valid, I want to know the slug in the params

for example

```
localhost:3000/test
Get('/:slug')
params.slug = test
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

NestJs doesn't support RegExp in the controller routes. It only accepts strings or an array of strings. Thus, you cannot set sophisticated patterns there.

> The characters ?, +, *, and () may be used in a route path, and are subsets of their regular expression counterparts. The hyphen ( -) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally by string-based paths.

[Source](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#route-wildcards)

However, you can get the request value and check it manually. If this way is okay for you then try something like this

```js
import {Controller, Get, Req} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Request} from 'express';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Get(':slug')
  test(@Req() request: Request) {
    const pattern = /[\w]+[.]+[\w]+/;
    if (pattern.test(request.url)) return 'bad';

    return 'good';
  }
}
```

Modify the pattern as you need.
The current example considers `something.txt` as bad (Anything including dot is bad) but `something` as a good pattern.

Comment: hmm I get the idea ... but this will not tell the browser to let's say fetch the file I requested. .... or I need to check my file in the public folder itself, read the content and then output

Comment: If you need to return the file (downloadable content) add appropriate headers and send the payload back. Or if it's an API request just process the data and return JSON instead (or whatever requirement you have). You already have `if` statement for that so the logic can be differentiated.